# mysql OperationalErrorr: (2059, <NULL>)

Tags: flask, mysql-python

When trying to connect to my local server (making a database entry - registration of a new user within a flask app) I'm getting the following error:

```
**_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)**
```

[Screenshot of the error Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq13Q.png)

Here's MySQL import to Python:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

MySQL config:

```
# Config MySQL
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] = "<password_ph>"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_DB"] = "myfirstdb"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"
# init MYSQL
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

[MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N9SK.jpg)

Here's usage of MySQL (The following code is within a registration function in Python)

```
# Create cursor
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
# Execute query
cur.execute("INSERT INTO myfirstdb.firstflaskapp(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
# Commit to DB
mysql.connection.commit()
# Close connection
cur.close()
```

The error seems to pop up at the line with:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Any idea what else might cause this error, please? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @dominik-remetei, it's right if you don't want to downgrade MySQL, you can use mysql.connector in addition :
pip install mysql-connector-python

Here's MySQL import to Python:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import mysql.connector
```

MySQL config:

```
#config my db
db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   passwd="<password_ph>",
   database='myfirstdb'
)
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Here's usage of MySQL in your route:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into ...')
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Error here.
In my Case, the problem was the version of MySql.

**Mysql Version 8 is not compatible with flask-sqlalchemy.**

I downgraded it to 5.7.22 and everthing worked fine.

Comment: Thank you @public_void. 
I found in the MySQL documentation and ended up using the connect() method from the mysql.connector module to configure the app and it worked fine after.
`conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host='localhost', user='root',password='<password_ph>',database='myfirstdb')`